# How automatcally solve a web quiz?

Tags: web, browser, automation, macros

I'm trying to win concert tickets by solving a web quiz (the only way to get these tickets, they don't sell them..). The annoying thing is: You only have a small chance to win at the end, so you have to do the quiz again and again until you (hopefully) win.

->How can I automate that?

- It's multiple choice, I have to click the radio button of the correct answer
- I know all answers of the quiz, so I know where to click
- Difficulty: The questions are not always in the same order, so it's not possible to automate it with a dumb "click-here-and-now-there"-macro.

There has to be something like:

```
while(true)
   if (question = "population of chicago") -> click "3 Millions"
   elsif (question = "highest mountain") -> click "everest"
   elsif (question = "biggest animal") -> click "blue whale"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think best solution would be using Selenium WebDriver and find the correct WebElement with the right answer text.